# Command to give players with specific scoreboard score modified leather armor not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been working on this command at least an hour and have had no luck.

```
/give @a[score_KitAntiArcher_min=0] minecraft:leather_leggings 1 0  {AttributeModifiers:[{Operation:0,UUIDLeast:1,UUIDMost:1,Amount:0.10,AttributeName:generic.movementSpeed,Name:Speed}],display:[{Name:"Speedy Leggings"},{color:0}]}
```

I was wondering if their is a way to do the following objective: Give Leather Pants to any player with a score of "KitAntiArcher" that's 1 or higher, with these data tags:

- +0.10 speed
- Leather pants must be colored black
- Custom name: Speedy Leggings

Before you say I can just get essentials and make a kit... please know I'm trying to avoid getting essentials at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to any player with a score of "KitAntiArcher" that's 1 or higher

Currently your selector (`@a[score_KitAntiArcher_min=0]`) will target anyone with `0` or higher. It should instead be `@a[score_KitAntiArcher_min=1]` for a minimum of `1`.

---

The only remaining problem I see is then with this part:

```
display:[{Name:"Speedy Leggings"},{color:0}]
```

`display` is not a list of compound tags, but instead just compound tag. It should therefore be:

```
display:{Name:"Speedy Leggings",color:0}
```

[Here's a wiki page on item NBT format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Item_structure).

---

The speed attribute should be working as-is, but keep in mind that `UUIDLeast:1,UUIDMost:1` needs to be unique, meaning you shouldn't have another attribute that also has `UUIDLeast:1,UUIDMost:1` that could be affecting the player at the same time.

It's usually best to have these be random numbers, so you don't end up accidentally reusing them.

---

Your fixed command should be:

```
/give @a[score_KitAntiArcher_min=1] minecraft:leather_leggings 1 0  {AttributeModifiers:[{Operation:0,UUIDLeast:1,UUIDMost:1,Amount:0.10,AttributeName:generic.movementSpeed,Name:Speed}],display:{Name:"Speedy Leggings",color:0}}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. also the score being 0 was on purpose for testing i just forgot to change it in the post